# Import to PostgreSQL from partly csv, partly JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, csv

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6, and I've got a table consisting of lots of columns.
I've got a csv-file containing the following format:

```
id, insert_time, JSON-object
```

The JSON-object has the following format:

```
{ column_nameY: valueX, column_nameY: valueY, ... }
```

The column_names in the JSON-object matches the columns in my PostgreSQL-table.

Is there a dynamic way to import such file, so I'll get the `id`, `insert_time`, and the remaining column values from the JSON object?

The order of columns in the JSON object might not match the order of the columns in the PostgreSQL table.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you know how to get that csv file imported into postgresql and that you know the fields inside that json object field.

first we create a table to store the contents of the csv file. Notice the datatype of that JSON field is jsonb.

```
create table test11 (id int, insert_time timestamp, json_object jsonb )
```

Know you import the csv file. but for illustration purposes, i will insert sample data into this Table.

```
insert into test11 (id, insert_time, json_object) values (1, '2017-11-14'::timestamp, '{ "column_nameX": "3", "column_nameY": "4" }'::jsonb);
insert into test11 (id, insert_time, json_object) values (1, '2017-11-14'::timestamp, '{ "column_nameX": "13", "column_nameY": "14" }'::jsonb);
```

we now select from that table;

```
Select id, insert_time,  json_object->>'column_nameY' as Column_NameY, json_object->>'column_nameX' as Column_NameX  from test11
```

your results should look like this...

```
id  |insert_time    |column_namey   |column_namex
1   |11/14/2017     |4              |3  
1   |11/14/2017     |14             |13
```

-HTH